# $L^2$ boundness of the operator corresponding to the Fourier multiplier

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $m:\Bbb{R}^d \to \Bbb{C}$ be the Fourier multiplier define the cooresponding operator $T_m$ as $$f \mapsto \mathcal{F}^{-1}(m\hat{f})$$ for $f\in \mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R}^d)$

Prove $T_m$ can be extended to  $L^2\to L^2$ bounded if and only if $m \in L^\infty$

My attempt:

First use the Plancherel's theorem we have $$\|T_mf\|_2 = \|m\hat{f}\|_2 \le \|m\|_\infty\|f\|_2 $$

Which implies $\|T_m\|_{2\to 2}  \le \|m\|_\infty$, I need to prove the other direction, I have no idea how to prove $\|m\|_\infty \le \|T_m\|_{2\to 2}$, maybe we can find $f$ to prove that the inequality above can be equal.

Comment: What do you mean by $S(\mathbb{R}^d)$ ?

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc
 $\mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R}^n)$ means Schwartz space. this condition makes the Fourier transformation and its inversion well defined .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space

Comment: Do you assume continuity of $m$  or at least finite number of discontinuities ? It makes things technically easier to handle.

Comment: No this condition also confuse me, in most of the harmonic analysis textbooks ,the continuity of the multiplier is not assumed  @Ryszard Szwarc

Comment: Calderon-Zygmund kernel  in your case should be translation invariant i.e it is of the form  on $K(x,y)=g(x-y).$ In your problem the operator $T_m.$ is the convolution operator with $g.$ The function $m$ is in some sense the Fourier transform of $g.$

Comment: A similar phenomenon appears in this post, which may be better defined , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4403840/360262

Comment: I have no idea, but I believe it has. Usually boundness of $T_m$ is easy as by Fourire transformation the operator $T_m$ is unitarily equivalent to multiplication operator with $m$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d.$ Once $m$ is measurable such operator is bounded if and only if $\|m\|_\infty <\infty.$ The main problem is to study the operator $T_m$ on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $1<p<2.$ Sometimes it is done by interpolation if $T_m$ is bounded on $L^1\mathbb{R}^d).$ In many important cases the operator $T_m$ is not bounded on $L^1\mathbb{R}^d),$ but is of so called weak type $(1,1).$

Comment: Perhaps you look into textbooks by E.M. Stein and G. Weiss, Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces. or  E.M. Stein. Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions . I have studied this material many years back.